# AWS NLB redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking

I currently have my subdomain poitning to the DNS name of my NLB (listening on TLS : 443)  via a CNAME,
i.e.

> https:// foo.mydomain.com

points to

> https ://foo-nlb-123456789.elb.region.amazonaws.com

The issue is one is unable to access the subdomain only by typing `foo.mydomain.com` and has to always type out the full path i.e. `https:// foo.mydomain.com`.
How can I access my subdomain (which points to the NLB) without having to type out the full path ?

Comment: Any reason for NLB? If you had ALB you could easly redirect http to https. With NLB you can't do this.

Comment: That is indeed the correct solution.

Comment: If you don't mind I will provide an answer regarding alb and nlb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The NLB does not allow for redirections of http into https, since these protocols operate at layer 7 of osi network stack.

Thus, ALB should be used as it provides ability to redirect http into https:

- [How can I redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS using an Application Load Balancer?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/)